# Modify each row of an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and a function that are both too complicated for an example, but all I want to do is modify each row in the data frame. The function simply takes a vector and modifies some of the values based on the other values, the dimensions remain the same.

```
newt = data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(t)){
  row = t[i,]
  newt = rbind(newt,f(row))
}
t = newt
```

Currently I'm using a for loop which I understand is both not the R-y way to do things and it is also exceedingly slow (I ~1million rows in my actual data).

I'm strongly trying to avoid plyr or data.table or any other package because there is a lot of code written already around the structure I have and I'd like to avoid extra complication. Apply seems to change everything to an array or matrix but my columns are of all sorts of types so this is not an option. I tried using adply from plyr but this was not memory efficient and crashed for decent sized input.

Comment: search for `apply` and `plyr`.   You want to do something along the lines of `apply(MyDF, 1, function)`

Comment: also, if you are doing this `newt = rbind(newt,f(row))`  1M times, that will likely be a bottle neck

Comment: As I said, I tried using plyr. t = adply(t, 1, f). even when t was only like 10 megs in size R would run until my machine ran out of memory and had to be killed by the OS (I have 16 GB of memory)

Answer (score 3):

It maybe be complicated at first, but the `data.table` and `plyr` packages are fantastic for this sort of thing. Once you get familiar with them you'll have no problem.

If your requirements are strictly to use `base` functions and avoid `apply`, you can get an efficiency boost by inserting each row into a data.frame rather than `rbind`ing:

```
> f = function(iRow) {if(iRow$A=="a") iRow$B == iRow$B * 2 ; return(iRow)}

> df = data.frame(A=letters[sample(1:26, 1000, replace=TRUE)], B=rnorm(1000))

> DF = data.frame(df[0,])
> system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {Row = df[i,] ; DF = rbind(DF, f(Row))})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.61    0.00    0.61 

> DF = data.frame(df[0,])
> system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {Row = df[i,] ; DF[i,] = f(Row)})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.28    0.00    0.28
```

If you learn to use `data.table`:

```
> system.time(dt[,B:=if(A=="a") B * 2,by=1:nrow(dt)])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.03
```

Comment: Well I don't have a requirement to avoid apply, I just don't know how to use it and maintain the column types in my data frame. Thanks for the suggestion about inserting vs rbinding, that should help a bit.