# R: How to convert from loops and rbinds to efficient code?

Tags: r, loops, csv, matrix, rbind

I'm new to R.  I have a problem to solve, and a working function below that solves it nicely (in decent time).  But, from what I'm reading on R tutorials, and here on SO, I feel like I'm doing way too much work to solve it.  Is there some fancy R way to collapse this all into a few lines?

The problem to solve:  Given a CSV file of data of character data, and a "flag" argument, extract the value at position [row, 1].  "row" is calculated to be the minimum value from column "InterestingColumn" for "flag a", the maximum value from column "Interesting Column" for "flag b", or the n-th value defined by a numeric "flag".  The output should be grouped by the unique values of "InterestingColumn".  The returned result should be a data frame.  The column schema is known, but the length of the file is not.

My instinct is that I should be able to get rid of the for loop altogether, and also that my reconstruction of the matrix with rbind each time is inefficient ([like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664004/modify-each-row-of-an-r-data-frame))  Any tutelage would be appreciated, thanks!

```
myfunc <- function(flag = "a") {
   csv <- read.csv("data.csv", colClasses = "character")
   col <- unique(csv$InterestingColumn)
   output <- NULL

   for (i in 1:length(col)) {
      sub <- subset(csv, InterestingColumn == col[i])
      vals <- as.numeric(sub[, 12])

      if (flag == "a") {
         output <- rbind(output, matrix(c(sub[which.min(vals),1], col[i]), ncol = 2))
      }
      else if (flag == "b") {
         output <- rbind(output, matrix(c(sub[which.max(vals),1], col[i]), ncol = 2))
      }
      else if (is.numeric(flag)) {
         output <- rbind(output, matrix(c(sub[flag,1], col[i]), ncol = 2))
      }

      colnames(output) <- c("data", "col")
      as.data.frame(output)
   }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you had example input, and the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, InterestingColumn is not column 12, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Say that column 12 is named `Col12`.  Then `aggregate` may be in order.  Everything after the `read.csv` call in the function should be handled by the following expression (but you may want to set the names of the resulting data frame):

```
aggregate(Col12 ~ InterestingColumn, data=csv, FUN=function(x) {
  if (flag == "a") {
    min(x);
  } else if (flag == "b") {
    max(x);
  } else if (is.numeric(flag)) {
    x[flag];
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks that's an interesting suggestion, I'll try it out.  You are correct that InterestingColumn is not 12, that was my typo.

Comment: The aggregate function definitely worked for extracting the correct value for x.  But, I am struggling with getting the next set of data that I need.  Once I have the correct value of Col12 for a given InterestingColumn, I need to extract a 3rd column of data for my final output.  I actually don't care about the value of Col12 for output, only calculate.  Is there a way to bring another column along for the ride inside aggregate?

Comment: I can search csv again for the the row that results from the aggregate function, and then extract my column, but that seems to kill any performance gains.